# Do I need to keep paying to play online on Starcraft 2?

Tags: starcraft-2

Do I need to keep paying after I buy the original CD of Starcraft 2?

I heard that the online part isn't free. Is this true? If this is the case, is it charged per hour or month? Do I need a "Premium account" or something like it?

If you could provide some info about what happens after you buy the original CD, it'd be appreciated.

Also: Is Steam needed at all or not?

Comment: I tried to make your question a little more clear and direct to the point. Could you check if I missed something you wanted ?

Comment: Thankyou for the edit, you changed the question from 'what is the system blizzard adapts for payement on online playing ' to ' do i have to pay after i buy an account ' .

Comment: More clear but, i need those negetive votes removed

Comment: I'm not the one who DV you ... I can't do anything about it. Try to improve the way you ask questions, so it'll help the vote issue (You have 3 questions that have being Down voteds (-5;-5;-6;)) You should try to create a question that you could answer. Try read it a couple of times before posting, also, try to use more markups tools (headers, html, bold, italic, blocks ...) may help you improve the questions that you make.

Comment: Also, the other two questions are the **same**. Try not to duplicate your own questions, just improve the one you already created. Other tip is, read about what kind of questions you should ask here (this is **NOT** a forum ... it's a little more complicated than that...), only questions related to gaming not "this hardware works with my game?" this is a question about hardware not gaming itself. You can ask those questions in the CHAT when you reach 20+ rep. You can "farm" rep by creating **GOOD** edits in question and answer around the site also creating **GOOD** answers and questions.

Comment: Starcraft 2 is free to play online except in very specific regions.  Its not clear if youa re in one of thee regions, although if you were in those regions, you would know if because you would be directed to pay.

Comment: @A.H if you think that the edit is not correct, you can click in the "edited x hours ago" and rollback for the version that is correct. Also, "what is the system blizzard adapts for payment on online playing" is ANOTHER question ... nothing to do with the first version of your question

Comment: Also "please if you do not know what i am saying stay away from the question, dont bug in others bussiness." **REALLY?** Now that I saw that ... -1 for you sir ... learn that you are dealing with people not your slaves ...

Answer (score 6):

You pay only once for Starcraft 2, you have to create a battlenet account if you don't have one and bind it to your starcraft.  You have to download the Blizzard launcher and than start playing starcraft 2. It's not connected to valve's steam.

Once you paid it's free. The Addon is not free but once you bought it you can play online as much as you want.

Answer (score 2):

Starcraft 2 is a game that you only pay for 1 time.

You can buy the game in a store where you take de box, cd..etc etc. and only  (battlenet store) where you have the digital copy.

When you buy the game you have "access" to the Main story (or campaing), arcades mode, etc.. and online. That **NOT** requires to month payments as WoW.

And no, Blizzard has nothing to see with Steam. Are two different companies, with diferent platforms. Blizzard has his own launcher to launch his games you buyed.